# Behat request working but return empty body

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I'm using Behat (https://github.com/Behat/Behat) in a symfony2 app, to test a REST API.

I have a weird problem with some of my scenario, they return a `200` code when the request is good but return an empty body, so the test is failing...

For exemple I made this scenario :

```
Scenario: I find all my DNS zones
    Given I set header "Authorization" with value "Bearer xxxxxxxxx"
    And I send a GET request to "/api/dns"
    Then the response code should be 200
    And the response should contain json:
    """
    {
    }
    """
    Then print response
```

This is what I get in my terminal avec the test is done :

```
Scenario: I find all my DNS zones                                # features/api/security.feature:28
Given I set header "Authorization" with value "Bearer xxxxxxxxx" # Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext::iSetHeaderWithValue()
And I send a GET request to "/api/dns"                           # Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext::iSendARequest()
Then the response code should be 200                             # Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext::theResponseCodeShouldBe()
And the response should contain json:                            # Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext::theResponseShouldContainJson()
  """
  {
  }
  """
Then print response                                              # Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext::printResponse()
  │ GET api/dns => 200:
  │ []
```

When I'm trying the same request with cURL in my terminal, like this

`curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxx" "http://localhost:8000/api/dns"`

It returning all the values :

> [{"id":1,"name":"yahoo.fr","owner_id":1,"create_date":"2016-02-25T11:53:07+0100"},{"id":2,"name":"dbmail.com","owner_id":223,"create_date":"2016-02-25T11:53:07+0100"},{"id":3,"name":"tiscali.fr","owner_id":223,"create_date":"2016-02-25T11:53:07+0100"},{"id":4,"name":"wanadoo.fr","owner_id":1,"create_date":"2016-02-25T11:53:07+0100"},{"id":5,"name":"hotmail.fr","owner_id":223,"create_date":"2016-02-25T11:53:07+0100"}]

I really don't know what is the problem... I have some of my scenario who are workign well and return datas...
I already searched on the Internet but I didn't find anything about this.

I don't know if somebody already have this issue.

Thank for your help.

**EDIT**

There is my Behat.yml

```
default:
gherkin:
    cache: app/cache/test/behat/behat_gherkin_cache
testers:
    rerun_cache: app/cache/test/behat/behat_rerun_cache
calls:
    error_reporting: 14335 # E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED
extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\WebApiExtension:
        base_url: 'http://nginx:8001'
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        sessions:
            default:
                symfony2: ~
suites:
    default:
        contexts:
         - Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext
         - FeatureContext
```

Comment: Where's that data coming from? If it's from a database is it the same for your dev environment as per your test environment?

Comment: Yes, this is from a local mysql DB, same datas for dev and test env

Comment: Looks like a configuration problem to me. It might help to find a solution if you also post your behat.yml configuration and triple check that the query is being run against the DB that you think is being run.

Comment: I have add my Behat.yml above. I think I have find the problem, my ap working with two DB in same time, and I should config my behat to query the DB 2 on some of my scenarios. If you know how, that would really help me :)